# How to access the specific elements in the array?

Tags: arrays, smarty

This is the assigning part of the smarty variable in controller file.

```
$objSmarty->assign( 'seleted_customer_subsidy_race_types', $this->getRequestData( array( 'customer_subsidy_race_types' ) ) );
```

We get this displayed:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
(
[subsidy_race_type_id] => 1
)
[2] => Array
(
[subsidy_race_type_id] => 2
[subsidy_race_sub_type_id] => 2
)
)
```

How to access `subsidy_race_type_id` and `subsidy_race_sub_type_id` fields specifically?

Comment: How does your template file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this

```
foreach($arr as $item) {
    print_r($item['subsidy_race_type_id']);
    print_r($item['subsidy_race_sub_type_id']);
}
```